# XSLT problem during transformation

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, namespaces, transform

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    version="1.0"  
    xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:infoRequest="ControlSkin3" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
    exclude-result-prefixes="xmlns">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />
```

I've got a problem during the transformation in xhtml, some elements like this : xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" are insered in a lot of my xhtml tag.

ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/style/js/etablissement/videos.js" 
    xmlns:infoRequest="ControlSkin3" 
    xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" ></script>
```

I'm working on IIS6. and I've no explanations.

Did you have already the same problem?
What's wrong about my code?

Thank you.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an explanation of the problem and for a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> exclude-result-prefixes="xmlns">
>
> What's wrong about my code?

This isn't quite meaningful, as there isn't any namespace prefix in the XSLT stylesheet, named `"xmlns"`.

On the other side, the existing prefixes are: `"ms"`, `"infoRequest"` and `"xsl"`.

If these prefixes are specified as a blank-separated list as the value of the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute, then they will not be present in the serialization (output) of any literal result element.

**For example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:infoRequest="ControlSkin3"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ms infoRequest xsl">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/style/js/etablissement/videos.js">
            /* Script code here */
          </script>
        </head>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is performed** (on any source XML document -- not used), **the result dosn't contain any unwanted namespaces**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/style/js/etablissement/videos.js">
            /* Script code here */
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude these namespaces by suppressing them via the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute. You need to list the namespace prefixes separated by whitespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    version="1.0"  
    xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:infoRequest="ControlSkin3" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
    exclude-result-prefixes="infoRequest ms">
```

Comment: I think that you need to refrase the first sentence as "You can exclude these namespaces **for literal result elements** ".